# What is the fundamental logic that tideSDK follows to bring UI across platform?

Tags: tidesdk

Probably this question may be a simple one. Still I have not got answer from WWW.

tideSDK provides UI Module, and through which we can create same UI across platforms [ mac, windows, Linux].

MY Question:
What is the backend library tideSDK uses to bring UI?.  Does it abstracts native UI Components and provides on presentation layer?  Confused.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

UI Module of TideSDK provides abstract layer on top of native UI components. This means that the implementation of windowing apis are all native to the platform.

Taking example: Users of TideSDK would write the code in JavaScript language. all the commands would be natively implemented using the standard windows apis for "Windows XP / Win7 / win 8", and the JavaScript code will translate the instructions in native code for windows and execute appropriate commands. The same JavaScript code in osx will translate to native commands of Mac OS. and the same way it would work for linux.

Backend Parts of TideSDK has been implemented in variety of languages (c++ or languages inherited from c++) including VC++, Objective C++, C++.

We use different compilers (including Microsoft Visual Studio, g++, xcode) for different OS.

So basically to answer your question: TideSDK is the bridge between natively implemented code and JavaScript. It tries to interpret the JavaScript and translates everything to native language which the underlying operating system understands. By doing this the users of TideSDK will see consistent interface while dealing with various native parts while TideSDK abstracts out the detail.

I have taken UI Module as an example here but there are many modules available in TideSDK which provides variety of native functionalities.. checkout the api docs [here](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/)